# Is there something like automatic writing or surrealist automatism in programming?

Tags: text, automation, nlp, markov-chains

Is there something like [automatic writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_writing) or [surrealist automatism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrealist_automatism) in programming?

Comment: There must be very advanced mechanisms in the Spam industry copying and mixing blocks of literature to make an E-Mail look like natural english. I don't know of any freely available solutions, though.

Comment: Hmmm, is there such mechanisms mixing blocks of open-source code so to create new working programs with unknown function? :)

Comment: Try github.com. Now I 'm totally in trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Perl is the closest thing that I can think of.

Comment: Not the answer the OP is looking for, but +1 :)